# PySpark Explode JSON String into Multiple Columns

Tags: json, pyspark, explode

I have a dataframe with a column of string datatype. The string represents an api request that returns a json.

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([
           ("[{original={ranking=1.0, input=top3}, response=[{to=Sam, position=guard}, {to=John, position=center}, {to=Andrew, position=forward}]}]",1)], 
           "col1:string, col2:int")
df.show()
```

Which generates a dataframe like:

```
+--------------------+----+
|                col1|col2|
+--------------------+----+
|[{original={ranki...|   1|
+--------------------+----+
```

The output I would like to have col2 and have two additional columns from the response. Col3 would capture the player name, indicated by to= and col 4 would have their position indicated by position=. As well as the dataframe would now have three rows, since there's three players. Example:

```
+----+------+-------+
|col2|  col3|   col4|
+----+------+-------+
|   1|   Sam|  guard|
|   1|  John| center|
|   1|Andrew|forward|
+----+------+-------+
```

I've read that I can leverage something like:

```
df.withColumn("col3",explode(from_json("col1")))
```

However, I'm not sure how to explode given I want two columns instead of one and need the schema.

Note, I can modify the response using json_dumps to return only the response piece of the string or...

```
[{to=Sam, position=guard}, {to=John, position=center}, {to=Andrew, position=forward}]}]
```

Comment: is it possible to change API so it return an **actual** json string, like `"to":"Sam"`, and not `to=Sam`?

Comment: Yes, I was calling .json() on the response. Instead I can do a json.loads() and maintain the json string. It then looks like "[{'original':{'ranking':1.0, 'input':'top3'}, 'response':[{'to':'Sam', 'position':'guard'}, {'to':'John', 'position':'center'}, {'to':'Andrew', 'position':'forward'}]}]",1)], 
           "col1:string, col2:int" .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you simplify the output like mentioned, you can define a simple JSON schema  and convert JSON string into `StructType` and read each fields

**Input**

```py
df = spark.createDataFrame([("[{'to': 'Sam', 'position': 'guard'},{'to': 'John', 'position': 'center'},{'to': 'Andrew', 'position': 'forward'}]",1)], "col1:string, col2:int")

# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
# |col1                                                                                                             |col2|
# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
# |[{'to': 'Sam', 'position': 'guard'},{'to': 'John', 'position': 'center'},{'to': 'Andrew', 'position': 'forward'}]|1   |
# +-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----+
```

And this is the transformation

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql import types as T

schema = T.ArrayType(T.StructType([
    T.StructField('to', T.StringType()),
    T.StructField('position', T.StringType())
]))

(df
    .withColumn('temp', F.explode(F.from_json('col1', schema=schema)))
    .select(
        F.col('col2'),
        F.col('temp.to').alias('col3'),
        F.col('temp.position').alias('col4'),
    )
    .show()
)

# Output
# +----+------+-------+
# |col2|  col3|   col4|
# +----+------+-------+
# |   1|   Sam|  guard|
# |   1|  John| center|
# |   1|Andrew|forward|
# +----+------+-------+
```